# Ajax Search Form with multiple Inputs In Wordpress with PHP and JQuery | Data Fetch

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

My code is working like charm but i need to add 2 dropdown into it:

this is where i input the value:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()" placeholder="Search..">    
</form>
```

and i want it to look like this:

```
 <form>
    <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()" placeholder="Search..">   
    <select>
       <option>location category</option>
       <option>option2</option>
    </select>
     <select>
       <option>category</option>
       <option>option2</option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

i put this code in functions.php its working fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
function fetch(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data:{ action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });

}
</script>

<?php
}

// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

    $the_query = new WP_Query( 
      array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 
        'post_type' => 'locations' 
      ) 
    );

    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();

$myquery = esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] );
$a = $myquery;
$search = get_the_title();
if( stripos("/{$search}/", $a) !== false) {?>
             
        <div class="city-results">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                <h3>
                <?php the_title();?>
                </h3>
            </a>
            
        </div>

        <?php }
    endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die();
}
?>
```

i guess we need to edit this area where fetching data

```
data:{ action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
```

i tried using this Method but is not working :

```
data:{ action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword , #keyword2').val() },
```

but i'm noob in Jquery/Ajax

if anyone help me here with this Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass both dropdown values to the `ajax` data parameter. check the below code.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" onkeyup="fetch()" placeholder="Search..">   
    <select name="location" id="location">
       <option>location category</option>
       <option>option2</option>
    </select>
     <select name="category" id="category">
       <option>category</option>
       <option>option2</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function fetch(){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'post',
            data:{ 
                action: 'data_fetch', 
                keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val(),
                location: jQuery('#location').val(),
                category: jQuery('#category').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
            }
        });

    }
</script>

// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

    echo $_POST['location']." ".$_POST['category'];

    $the_query = new WP_Query( 
      array( 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ), 
        'post_type' => 'locations' 
      ) 
    );

    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post();

        $myquery = esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] );
        $a = $myquery;
        $search = get_the_title();
        if( stripos("/{$search}/", $a) !== false) {?>
                     
                <div class="city-results">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                        <h3>
                        <?php the_title();?>
                        </h3>
                    </a>
                    
                </div>

        <?php }
    endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die();
}
```

Comment: @abdullah butt does my answer help?